# complex-analytic structure on the generic fibre

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

Here's something that's probably well known to many here, and I'd like to have a suitable reference.  I've got a map $f\colon X\to Y$ of complex spaces whose restriction to dense open subspaces $f\colon U\to V$ is the projection of a fibre bundle.  Suppose also that $X$ and $Y$ are affine varieties, so that I can consider the fibres of the map $f$ in two different categories.  That is, if $p\in V$ is a closed point, I could refine the Zariski topology on the fibre $f^{-1}(p)$ to the complex topology, and the result (I expect) must be homeomorphic to the same fibre in the category of complex spaces.  (If true, I could probably learn this much from, say, Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry*.)

This leads to my question.  Instead of looking at fibres over closed points, I'd probably prefer handling the fibre of $f$ over the generic point of $Y$, which I'll call $f^{-1}(\eta)$. (Does the property that $f$ restricts to a fibre bundle translate to something nice about the variety $f^{-1}(\eta)$?)   But I would want to compare the generic fibre, as a topological space, with the typical fibre of $f$ (as a complex space): I'd like to say that, suitably (re)topologized, the two notions of fibre are homeomorphic.  However,  I don't know how to refine the Zariski topology on the generic fibre, since my base field is now a function field (instead of $\mathbb C$).  Does anyone know of some good reading that might sort me out?

Comment: You could use the Lefschetz principle to write the generic fiber as the base change of a variety defined over a finitely generated field extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, and then embed $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ to "think of" the generic variety as a complex variety (which then has a corresponding complex analytic space).  However, Serre's examples suggest the corresponding topological space may depend on the choice of embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.  I should probably include a reference to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90551/what-does-the-lefschetz-principle-in-algebraic-geometry-mean-exactly/  -- it would be great if you would like to expand.  Is that to say that obtaining a complex-analytic space from the generic fibre may be possible, but not functorially?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that for any finite type variety over a characteristic $0$ field, there is non-canonically associated a complex analytic space.  Non-surprisingly, these different complex analytic spaces will typically be non-biholomorphic.  What was surprising when Serre first wrote down examples, is that these complex analytic spaces can also be non-homeomorphic.  

Comment: Sounds good -- if you wouldn't mind giving the reference to Serre as an answer, I'll accept it, although I'm not sure yet if my fibre bundle condition makes things any more special.