# Interesting algebraic geometry over large fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there any interesting algebro-geometric phenomena that happen over large algebraically closed fields of characteristic 0 and do not happen over $\mathbb{C}$ ("large" means cardinality larger than continuum)? I won't define interesting here, let's say something that can be appreciated by a person who doesn't know set theory.

A precise version of Lefschetz principle was mentioned on MO e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/90554) but I do not see if it excludes such thing from happening.

Comment: When I've read the title I've remembered an easy proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz which only works over uncountable fields - most (all?) proofs easily reduce to showing that a field $K$ finitely generated as an algebra over another field $k$ is an algebraic extension. It is easy to see $K/k$ is countably-dimensional. If $k$ is uncountable and $x\in K$ is transcendental over $k$, then $(x-\alpha)^{-1},\alpha\in k$ would be an uncountable linearly independent set. Of course, this one works over $\mathbb C$, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users